# Google Apps Script error Response Code: 413. Message: response too large

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to export MDM Data from Google Apps admin panel using this script \
The script is generating only 200 entries and then it throws an error message "Response Code: 413. Message: response too large"

Please help me to fix the concern

```js
function loadMobileDevices(query) {
  var pageToken, page;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // First we remove the existing content from the active sheet
  sheet.getActiveSheet().clearContents();
  // Then we add the headers to the active sheet
  sheet.appendRow([
    'Resource Id',
    'Device Id',
    'Status',
    'Type',
    'Email',
    'First Sync',
    'Last Sync',
    'Hardware Id',
    'Model',
    'Name',
    'OS',
    'serialNumber',
    'Deviceimei',
    'supportsWorkProfile'
  ]);
  // Try to retrieve the mobile devices, show msg box containing the error if it fails 
  try {
    do {
      page = AdminDirectory.Mobiledevices.list('my_customer', {
        maxResults: 500,
        pageToken: pageToken,
        allowLargeResults: true,
        query: query

      });
      var devices = page.mobiledevices;
      if (devices) {
        //for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
          var device = devices[i];
          // You can customize the list of fields choosing from:
          // https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices
          // Remember to adjust the column header accordingly
          sheet.appendRow([
            device.resourceId,
            device.deviceId,
            device.status,
            device.type,
            device.email[0],
            device.hardwareId,
            device.firstSync,
            device.lastSync,
            device.model,
            device.name,
            device.os,
            device.serialNumber,
            device.imei,
            device.supportsWorkProfile
          ]);
        }
      }
      pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
    } while (pageToken);
  } catch(err) {
    Browser.msgBox(err.message);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you add this code to your question instead of commenting it? And please also format it as code. So far your question is not very clear on what you're trying to achieve. Please add that to your question as well.

Comment: Please refer the detailed info + Script

Comment: Seems like this 403 error is not specific to GAS. A [403 error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E413.html) could be encountered when either the request/entity/response/or any part of the exchange is too large for the server to handle. For this case, it seems that you're retrieving a lot of data. If possible, try to retrieve data by batch of `n` (`n` = amount that you think is reasonable) and see if that works.